# Concurrent sort

Tags: arrays, sorting, go, concurrency

I am getting a deadlock error, have been banging my head for a while, any help would be appreciated. Below is what the program should do. I am looking for an explanation on why its breaking and if I can improve on my thought process

"
Write a program to sort an array of integers. The program should partition the array into 4 parts,
each of which is sorted by a different goroutine. Each partition should be of approximately equal size. Then the main goroutine should merge the 4 sorted subarrays into one large sorted array.

The program should prompt the user to input a series of integers. Each goroutine which
sorts ¼ of the array should print the subarray that it will sort. When sorting is complete,the main goroutine should print the entire sorted list.
"

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "os"
    "sort"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "sync"
)

func splitAndSortList(intList []int, chunkSize float64, chunkLength int, i int, wg sync.WaitGroup, c chan []int) {
    listN := intList[i*chunkLength : (i*chunkLength)+chunkLength]
    sort.Ints(listN)
    c <- listN
    fmt.Println("Sorted Chunk: n -", i, " List", listN)
    wg.Done()
}

func stringToInt(strList string, chunkSize float64) []int {
    var intList []int
    for _, s := range strings.Fields(strList) {
        i, err := strconv.Atoi(s)
        if err == nil {
            intList = append(intList, i)
        }
    }
    return intList
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Enter a sequence of integers: ")
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    numList, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')

    chunkSize := 4.0
    intList := stringToInt(numList, chunkSize)
    floatListLen := float64(len(intList))
    chunkLength := int(math.Ceil(float64(floatListLen / chunkSize)))

    c := make(chan []int, chunkLength)
    semiSortedList := []int{}

    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for i := 0; i < int(chunkSize); i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go splitAndSortList(intList, chunkSize, chunkLength, i, wg, c)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    close(c)
    for l := range c {
        semiSortedList = append(semiSortedList, l...)
    }

    fmt.Println("after sort", semiSortedList)
    fmt.Println("Sorting Complete")
}
```

Comment: You must not copy a sync.WaitGroup as explicitely stated in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

There are two bugs in the code.

1. chunkLength is small than chunkSize. Therefore, you will block inside of splitAndSortList function for `c <- listN`, and it will never call wg.Done().

```golang
    c := make(chan []int, chunkLength)

    for i := 0; i < int(chunkSize); i++ {
```

2. You must not pass sync.WaitGroup by value. Because you will get a copy of it, and then call wg.Done() on the copy. The original wait group will block forever. `func splitAndSortList(wg *sync.WaitGroup)`

---

Here is working code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "os"
    "sort"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "sync"
)

func splitAndSortList(intList []int, chunkSize float64, chunkLength int, i int, wg *sync.WaitGroup, c chan []int) {
    listN := intList[i*chunkLength : (i*chunkLength)+chunkLength]
    sort.Ints(listN)
    c <- listN
    fmt.Println("Sorted Chunk: n -", i, " List", listN)
    wg.Done()
}

func stringToInt(strList string, chunkSize float64) []int {
    var intList []int
    for _, s := range strings.Fields(strList) {
        i, err := strconv.Atoi(s)
        if err == nil {
            intList = append(intList, i)
        }
    }
    return intList
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Enter a sequence of integers: ")
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    numList, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')

    chunkSize := 4.0
    intList := stringToInt(numList, chunkSize)
    floatListLen := float64(len(intList))
    chunkLength := int(math.Ceil(float64(floatListLen / chunkSize)))

    c := make(chan []int, int(chunkSize))
    semiSortedList := []int{}

    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for i := 0; i < int(chunkSize); i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go splitAndSortList(intList, chunkSize, chunkLength, i, &wg, c)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    close(c)
    for l := range c {
        semiSortedList = append(semiSortedList, l...)
    }

    fmt.Println("after sort", semiSortedList)
    fmt.Println("Sorting Complete")
}
```

Comment: "You should never pass sync.WaitGroup by value". N. this is not a "should", this should read "MUST NOT".

Comment: Thanks a lot folks, appreciate the explanation :)